# instead of uploading single image how to upload multiple image

Tags: javascript

This I have implemented in javascript. So in this if user uploads a image it will display the image and also image name. So here presently i am able to upload single image. So how can we upload multiple images in this case if any one have an idea please let me know

```js
var loadFile = function(event) { 
  var image = document.getElementById('output'); 
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]); 
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<img id="output" width="200" />
```

Comment: Add the `multiple` attribute on the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `multiple` attribute on `input` to accept multiple images, and use a `for` loop, to iterate over the files, and display each one of them.

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
    image.id = "output";
    image.width = "200";
    document.querySelector(".cont").appendChild(image);
  }
};
```

```html
<p><input multiple type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" style=""></p>
<p class="cont"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It is working